# selecting first child of XMLList

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex3, xmllist

I have an application in Flex that retrieves XMLList (Tests) from a remote site which suppose to normally contain 5 children (Test) I use for each to loop through the XMLList and  do some chartings which works fine. In some weird cases I received up to 10 children in my XMList and my application chose to use the last 5 whereas the correct set suppose to be the first 5 sets. How do i select just the first 5 sets and ignoring the last sets?

```
<Tests count="10">
    <Test unix_time="1378375047" client="25478955" id="831527">
        <means>502</means>
        <variance>56.3</variance>
        <frequency>50</frequency>
    </Test>
    <Test unix_time="1378375047" client="25478955" id="831529">
        <means>502</means>
        <variance>56.3</variance>
        <frequency>50</frequency>
    </Test>
    <Test unix_time="1378375047" client="25478955" id="831526">
        <means>502</means>
        <variance>56.3</variance>
        <frequency>50</frequency>
    </Test>
    <Test unix_time="1378375047" client="25478955" id="831528">
        <means>502</means>
        <variance>56.3</variance>
        <frequency>50</frequency>
    </Test>
    <Test unix_time="1378375047" client="25478955" id="831530">
        <means>502</means>
        <variance>56.3</variance>
        <frequency>50</frequency>
    </Test>

    <Test unix_time="1378375200" client="25478955" id="831652">
        <means>600</means>
        <variance>44</variance>
        <frequency>45</frequency>
    </Test>
    <Test unix_time="1378375200" client="25478955" id="831654">
        <means>600</means>
        <variance>44</variance>
        <frequency>45</frequency>
    </Test>
    <Test unix_time="1378375200" client="25478955" id="831651">
        <means>600</means>
        <variance>44</variance>
        <frequency>45</frequency>
    </Test>
    <Test unix_time="1378375200" client="25478955" id="831653">
        <means>600</means>
        <variance>44</variance>
        <frequency>45</frequency>
    </Test>
    <Test unix_time="1378375200" client="25478955" id="831655">
        <means>600</means>
        <variance>44</variance>
        <frequency>45</frequency>
    </Test>
</Tests>
```

Comment: After reading from xml..you can sort the elements based on id attribute values then use first five elements only...

Comment: thanks for this response. suppose i want to sort on unix_time please how do i go about it.

Comment: unix_time also seems to be same ..better  to go with id value only

Comment: Thanks The first 5 of unix_time are the same while the last five is some three minutes earlier. id is unique though. but how do I do it?

Comment: do you want the code... i can do it in Java

Comment: That's fine. though I am using Action script but I can use the logic  of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this. I used the unix-time to choose between start time and endtime.